# Why so many non-Ruby developers built Rails-like frameworks inspired in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Rails inspired:

PHP developers to write [cakePHP](http://cakephp.org/),
JavaScript developers to write [Railway.JS](http://railwayjs.com/)
and Python developers to write [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (I'm not sure about this one).

Why so many non-Ruby developers built Rails-like frameworks inspired in Ruby on Rails?
(I'm not very sure if some of the frameworks I mentioned above were written before Rails)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django was released on Jul 2005; Ruby on Rails came out a year earlier.

You don't mention Grails for Java; it's based on Spring, Hibernate, and Groovy.

I don't think there's anything unique about Ruby or any homage going on.  It says that developing CRUD-based web apps is a problem that's common to lots of languages.  It's natural that someone would try to solve the problem using convention over coding in their favorite.

Comment: Great point. This is more of a global affirmation going on with RESTful architecture. But Rails was developed as soon as this philosophy emerged and has been a cornerstone to its history where as the older languages had to adapt to it.

Comment: Ruby as an object-oriented language is older than Rails, if I remember my history right.  Having a web framework for CRUD-based apps is no more central to the design of the language than it was for any of the other languages.  I would argue that Struts 1.0 was the first attempt as a framework for web-based apps.  That was back in 2000-2001.  It could be argued that Ruby took Struts a step further.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say Django is inspired  by Rails. Those two frameworks are quite different in several ways: Django does not have Rails-like controllers, its query API is very different compared to Rails, and the views are also different (and IMHO much better that Rails' - the template language, real template inheritance). And Django does not follow the RESTful way of doing CRUD.